# Как создать stackdump файл для программы?

Tags: c, отладка, gdb

Отлаживаю одну программу, в ходе выполнения прилетает SIGSEGV. Решил через gdb посмотреть стек вызовов, но gdb не может определить имя функции в которой проблема, и происходит следующее:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                                                  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Поэтому я решил использовать .stackdump файл, но программа почему то его не создала (хотя обычно при SIGSEGV он появлялся). Я полистал SO, по гуглил, полистал книжку Р. Столлмана про gdb, но так ничего и не нашёл. Вопрос: как создать stackdump файл программы?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что исходного кода нет?

Comment: определённости ради, что ты имеешь в виду под «*stackdump*»?

Comment: Может быть `coredump`?

Comment: А в дампе будет аналогичная картина. Попробуйте использовать valgrind в паре со встроенным gdb сервером - может быть он он зафиксирует ошибку до того, как стек будет совсем разбомблен. Ну и всякие прочие санитайзеры тоже можно попробовать.

Comment: Компилируйте с `-g -ggdb` и будет вам счастье.